# Override CSS with browser prefix

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

My page has a display issue on pageload with Safari (display inline-block element has a width of 0, after one JS inline style its fine). I can fix the issue with this extra style for my span element:

```
display: inline-block; //standard for all browsers
display: -webkit-inline-box; //safari fix
```

I have to use at first the standard and after that my fix. On the current browser versions it looks good for FF, IE 9-11, Chrome and Safari (Desktop Mac).

My question is now: Is the order fine or can i get with some browsers a problem? 
(Maybe browsers think: "Oh I have to make the inline element (span) to display:inline-block". And with the next line "Oh I dont know that property (-webket-inline-flex), so I use the standard display: inline".)

Hopefully you know what I mean? :)

Comment: Do you have any reference on your issue ? I've been using inline-block for years and never noticed any problem with Safari...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is fine, *however* you will find that any browser which supports `-webkit-inline-box` will use this over `inline-block`. This may cause issues as the way the browser-prefixed version is implemented may not reflect how the non-browser-prefixed version is implemented.

For instance, Google Chrome supports `-webkit-inline-box` and will use this instead of `inline-block`. Off the top of my head `webkit-inline-box` is based on the old out-dated version of the Flexbox specification.

Perhaps a better solution would be to work out why Safari is giving your `inline-block` element a width of 0. This isn't behaviour I've witnessed myself, but Safari usually falls outside of the production browsers I test in.